# Почему не выводится выбранное значение?

Tags: javascript

Есть у меня вот такой код:

```js
const input141 = document.querySelector('.i-141');
const input142 = document.querySelector('.i-142');
const out14 = document.querySelector('.out-14');
const s143 = document.querySelector('.s-143');

function f14() {
  out14.innerHTML = (s143.value);
  out14.innerHTML = (typeof s143.value);
}

document.querySelector('.b-14').onclick = f14;
```

```html
<select class="s-143">
  <option>+</option>
  <option>-</option>
  <option>*</option>
  <option>/</option>
</select>
<button class="b-14">Нажми</button>
<div class="out-14"></div>
```

Почему не выводятся полученные значения из `<select>`? Выводится только тип данных.

Comment: Удалите строку `out14.innerHTML = (typeof s143.value);` и будет вам значение. Сами просите всё содержимое заменить на строковое представление типа данных, и сами же удивляетесь, почему вам их показывают... Проблемой было бы какое-либо иное поведение

Comment: @Вася Воронцов ааа, переприсвоение точно!

Answer (score 1):

Конкатенацию забыли?

```js
const input141 = document.querySelector('.i-141');
const input142 = document.querySelector('.i-142');
const out14 = document.querySelector('.out-14');
const s143 =  document.querySelector('.s-143');

function f14(){
    out14.innerHTML = (s143.value);
    out14.innerHTML += (typeof s143.value);
}

document.querySelector('.b-14').onclick = f14;
```

```html
<select class="s-143"> 
  <option>+</option>
  <option>-</option>
  <option>*</option> 
  <option>/</option>
</select>
<button class="b-14">Нажми</button>
<div class="out-14"></div>
```